# Extract Equation type of image from MS Word in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

While importing the table content of **MSWord** fetching the `XML` of particular cell content those also have the Maths equation for which wordml(Word-XML) gives us the image of type `wmz` and provide us the image string of the same.
So I used that image string to create the image and save through our application at some particular location using code as below.

```
if (imageType == "wmz")
{
    GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
    int readCount;
    byte[] data = new byte[128];

    do
    {
        readCount = gzipStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        outStream.Write(data, 0, readCount);
    }
    while (readCount == 128);

    File.WriteAllBytes(path + @"\XMLPictureWmf.wmf", outStream.GetBuffer());
    outStream.Close();
    outStream.Dispose();

    Metafile mf;
    mf = new Metafile(path + @"\XMLPictureWmf.wmf");
    mf.Save(path + @"\XMLPicturepng.png");

    imageString = path + @"\XMLPicturepng.png";
}
```

Now if I am going for creating *png/jpeg* type of image I get the blank space for the same so in order to get image save i have to use `wmf` as image type.

So the problem arises when I save that image as `wmf`. Image use get bold and doesn't use to get the exact image as of word.

Kindly help me out to extract the `wmz` type of image from wordml(word-XML) with exact match and resolution as of word.

My code of fetching the word cell content in form of `XML` from Word doc is as follows:

```
public string GetImagefromWord(string filePath)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(filePath, miss, miss, miss, miss);

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Row aRow in docs.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Cell aCell in aRow.Cells)
        {
            string xml = aCell.Range.XML;
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
            ****//xpictNode-Node of word XML having Image****
            string imageType = xpictNode.Attributes["w:name"].Value.Substring(xpictNode.Attributes["w:name"].Value.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(xdoc.xpictNode.InnerText);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
            string img = "&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src= data:image/bmp;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(GetImageString(memoryStream, path, imageType))) + " />";
            //Function GetImageString() is shown above
        }
    }
}
```

[image: fetched Word XML Image]